# CV with Latex: is a beautiful design really possible?

Tags: typography, moderncv, examples, big-list, europecv

I make my CV with Latex and a french sty file for years now, nothing fancy to be honest.

Looking for some inspiration, I found [some astonishing examples](http://www.techblogstop.com/50-most-creative-resume-design-ideas/) of CV online, and I've seen on the other [threads right here showing the beauty of Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends); and I would like to see what can be done with the CV class. What I see [in this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae) is not really convincing (I have the same output).

Have you some great examples—eccentric or classic ones?

Comment: Combined with some vector-graphics editor (e.g. Illustrator), absolutely – don't make your far more difficult than it needs to be by stubbornly sticking to a pure-TeX solution. One of TeX's strengths is its versatility and robustness.  Note that the `cv` class isn't the end-all, be-all of CV/résumé LaTeX classes.  [I made mine starting from the `article` class.](http://www.seanallred.com/sean-allred.pdf)

Comment: @SeanAllred well, TiKZ could serve you as well ;-) And I suspect that in the "astonishing examples" link, the "John Doe" one is made with LaTeX.

Comment: @Astrinus `don't make your far more difficult than it needs to be` :) All things are possible, but not all things are logical.  Each of them could be made with TeX/TikZ and I can explain how they could be put together, but this doesn't mean I would want to do it :)

Comment: @SeanAllred That's the point: is it logical or ideological to insist on doing a Latex resume? It's a bit provocative question, but from an etymological point of view, _provocare_ is about looking for answers ;)

Comment: @KOthetypo *provocare* is about eliciting responses, not just answers ;) I wouldn't do my résumé in anything else, but I would not hesitate to use external tools to create the resources needed in the LaTeX.  Images, designs, etc.  For some tasks, I would even create 'pre-documents' (in the same vein as After Effects precomps) to make life easier.  Don't try to do everything all at once in one place.

Comment: The main thrust of the question here: _Have you some great examples—eccentric or classic ones?_ is essentially the same as the question at [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80). It boils down to "Show me your beautiful resume/CV in LaTeX". If you feel the answers there are not satisfactory, you could consider adding a bounty to that question to attract a new wave of good answers.

Comment: Consider the audience, too. For many fields, those CVs may be fun or interesting or challenging (or whatever) to create, but would be a terrible idea to use in practice.  Even for the world of graphic design (about which I claim *no* expertise/experience), I wonder if many of those examples [obfuscate the information](http://xkcd.com/1273/) they are trying to present.... Of course, it may be fun for some people to torture TeX into producing something like this.

Comment: I also agree with @SeanAllred regarding more traditional CVs: just use a basic class. It allows for much more flexibility.

Comment: Anything is possible, but I think this question isn't focussed enough to really work in a Q&A site so I voted to close as too broad.

Comment: "Questions asking for a list of alternatives with no definitive answer"(`big-list` tag definition). I think it's a relevant question, thereby.

Comment: If it's closed, I think it should be duped to the other resume/CV question. I've now voted as such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)

Comment: A friend of mine built a CV similar, I made some updated to work in French an I have add a cover letter. 
The source code is [here](https://github.com/davebulaval/CV_template) .