# simple two column CV

Tags: two-column, moderncv

I have already read [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae). What I need is just a simple two column latex cv. it should look like this:

[image: example]

Please note that this is added at the bottom of an existing document. And this document already uses a customized class. So, I think, just using another class for the CV is no option.

Basically I would just like to know, how to achieve a formatting similar to the one in the image.

Comment: Just use a `longtable` with two columns

Comment: Or use `\marginpar` for the left column

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `longtable`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \bfseries\Large
  Curriculum Vitae
\end{center}
  \begin{longtable}{@{}>{\raggedleft}p{0.25\linewidth}|
                          p{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}@{}}
    Address  & Some address \\
             & Again some address\\
             & and again\\[1em]
    Date of birth & 12.02.2015 \\[1em]
    Education & \lipsum[1] \\[1em]
              & xxxxx \\[1em]
              & \lipsum[2] \\[1em]
              & xxxxx \\[1em]
              & \lipsum[3] \\[1em]
              & xxxxx
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]