# Align address blocks in a resume

Tags: resume, cv

I'm trying to align three address blocks so that there is one on the left alignment, one on the right alignment and one in the center. This is what I have so far for two addresses (I used a lot of this from a template):

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\textwidth=5.2in % increase textwidth to get smaller right margin
\linespread{0.97}
\newenvironment{nitemize}{%
  \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]%
}{%
  \end{itemize}%
}

\begin{document} 
\address{{\bf Address1} \\ Filler Text \\ Filler Text}
\address{{\bf Address2} \\ Filler Text \\ Filler Text}
```

This is what it looks like right now

```
Address1                                                   Address2
 Filler                                                     Filler
 Filler                                                     Filler
```

This is what I want it to look like

```
Address1                     Address2                      Address3
 Filler                       Filler                        Filler
 Filler                       Filler                        Filler
```

Is there any way that I could make it work with three address blocks?

Also, I'm not using the middle address block for an actual address. I want to use it for a name instead, but I could not get the name block to show between the two address blocks so if there is any way I could get a text block to show between the two addresses, that would also be an acceptable answer to me.

Comment: Your example is not a MWE. Could you please edit your Original Post ?

Comment: Aditionally, `res.cls` is very old and considered obsolete, i.e. should not be used anymore.

Comment: [Q&A on packages/templates/document classes for résumés](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80/31685)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 
\newcommand\Address[1]{\tabular{c}#1\endtabular\hfill}    
\begin{document} 
Test    

    \Address{{\bf Address1} \\ Filler Text \\ Filler Text}
    \Address{{\bf Address2} \\ Filler Text \\ Filler Text}
    \Address{{\bf Address3} \\ Filler Text \\ Filler Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `\minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document} 
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
  \textbf{Address1}\\
  Filler Text\\
  Filler Text
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.34\textwidth}
  \textbf{Address2}\\
  Filler Text\\
  Filler Text
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
  \textbf{Address3}\\
  Filler Text\\
  Filler Text
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Minipages should do what you want. You can format the text within each minipage as you like, and then you don't need to use the `res` document class, now obsolete according to the comment by @Johannes_B.

[image: Output screenshot]