# Looking for a resume template

Tags: templates, cv

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question. I hope that, if not, you can try to suggest others destinations.
So my question is very simple but it takes me lot of time due to the fact that i'm a beginner user of latex.
QUESTION: Are there any Curriculum Vitae templates to use in LaTeX?  Or any packages build up to write a CV?

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae

Comment: thanks. Is that template  an official european CV? You know that in Europe there is a standard template to use.

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/europecv

Comment: the class `moderncv` is quite interesting in my opinion. It is badly documented though. Checking for templates like @Victor suggested, seem to be a good way to find a fitting class.

Answer (score 0):

U can try with this
[ShareLatex templates](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/)

Also see [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae-StackExchange Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)