# Etaremune with resume class

Tags: numbering, enumerate, resume, cv, etaremune

I am using the etaremune package with the resume class. They don't seem to cooperate in the sense that the numbering of the entries in etarumene is the same it is with enumerate.

Here the etaremune works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etaremune}

\begin{document}

\begin{etaremune}
\item T.~Brander, A.~Hannukainen. \textbf{Numerical study of the enclosure method for $p$-Laplacian}.
\item T.~Brander, B.~von Harrach, M.~Kar, M.~Salo. {\bfseries Monotonicity and enclosure methods for the $p$-Laplace equation}.
\item T.~Brander, J.~Ilmavirta, M.~Kar. {\bfseries Superconductive and insulating inclusions for linear and non-linear conductivity equations}.
\end{etaremune}

\end{document}
```

But here the ordering is the same as with the enumerate package:

```
\documentclass{resume}
\usepackage{etaremune}

\begin{document}

\begin{etaremune}
\item T.~Brander, A.~Hannukainen. \textbf{Numerical study of the enclosure method for $p$-Laplacian}.
\item T.~Brander, B.~von Harrach, M.~Kar, M.~Salo. {\bfseries Monotonicity and enclosure methods for the $p$-Laplace equation}.
\item T.~Brander, J.~Ilmavirta, M.~Kar. {\bfseries Superconductive and insulating inclusions for linear and non-linear conductivity equations}.
\end{etaremune}

\end{document}
```

Is there an easy way of fixing this?

(I hope the resume class is standard enough for people to know it. Here is the copyright information from the class:

```
RESUME DOCUMENT STYLE -- Released 23 Nov 1989
for LaTeX version 2.09
Copyright (C) 1988,1989 by Michael DeCorte
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `res` class (which also circulates under the name `resume`) was released in 1989 as a LaTeX2.09 style file. Then it was embellished to become a LaTeX2e class.

It *can* cooperate with other packages such as `etaremune` provided the completely wrong `\nofiles` command is removed from the class code.

Indeed you can see in the log file

```
\gdef\etaremune@i{3}

LaTeX Warning: Etaremune labels have changed.
               Rerun to get them right.
```

The top line means that the essential bit of information is not written in the `.aux` file (because it's not written at all), so in subsequent runs there is no way to know the number of items.

If you remove the `\nofiles` instruction, then you get, after two runs, the expected result.

Don't use `res`. It's almost thirty years old. There are much better tools nowadays.

Comment: The better might be found here, I guess: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80/