# Is there any stylish/colorful CV writing package?

Tags: cv

[image]

[CV link](https://nl.freepik.com/vrije-vector/moderne-web-developer-cv-sjabloon_1000086.htm).

I can make CV in LaTeX using the moderncv package. I also saw the [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae). But I don't see yet above type of CV writing in LaTeX. Is there any package on this?

Comment: Have a look at `limecv`. It is pretty colorful.

Comment: If you are a web developer, then maybe creating a web-based cv would be easier/nicer? You could include a link in a job application letter, or print the web page as pdf (the `wkhtmltopdf` utility can help to create a proper pdf with background colors etc), or create a simple cv with `moderncv` and add a remark saying 'if you want to see the online version of the cv which has a very nice layout and shows my web developer abilities, go to the following url:'

Comment: Search for twenty secondscv template on LaTeX templates.com