# Removing or changing table border spacing in `longtable`

Tags: longtable, columns, resume, cv, border

I want to remove the border spacing of a table created by `longtable` package. I wish to preserve the column spacing as such and wish to only remove the right side border spacing so that a two column table spanning in two pages will be well aligned. I'm  aware of using `\brgin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}` for removing table border space in normal `table` or `tabular` environment. I'm using the table for creating a table inside a section of my resume made using `res.cls`. I've also attached a screenshot of the problem that I'm facing.

[image: Screenshot of the issue faced]

Comment: `@{}` also works in `longtable`s. You might want to add the `l` option as in `\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}l}`.

Comment: Apart from that, you might want to use an alternative for the very ols `res.cls`. Alternative might be found for example here: [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80/134144)

Comment: I do use other templates made using `moderncv` and other packages. This one is for academic purpose. I tried `\begin{longtable}[@{}ll]`, but the table collapsed and now it's like the skills section is looking like it's written using normal line breaks. @leandriis

Comment: it is always better to show your input as code, you could use `@{}` to remove the inter-column space but what we can not see without code is why the text "National institute..." is not already aligned

Comment: if you really used `\begin{longtable}[@{}ll]` then you would have had multiple errors reported, the column specifications have to go in a mandatory `{}` argument not an optional `[]` one. Please show your actual code, in a code block in your question.

Comment: Can you check both the images.It has the screenshot of the codes that I tried to resolve the issue. @DavidCarlisle https://imgur.com/D08j5A8, https://imgur.com/oZwC0im

Comment: First one (https://imgur.com/D08j5A8) didn't give any errors but the alignment is not correct. The second one gave multiple errors as you told. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: please do not use external links and do not post code as an image, put a small complete document as text in your question

Comment: however your code image (the first one) make it clear that despite the red lines you added to the image in the question there is no alignment specified the "National Insti..." text and the Softwares... text are in separate tables which do not have fixed width columns so will not be alogned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93823/discussion-between-govind-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`longtable` are centred by default so you want a left-algned one with no column padding on the left so

```
\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}ll}
```