# LaTex CV- Deedy Resume: How to change the Color of Name and the Subsections?

Tags: xetex, cv, deedy-resume

How can I change the colour of the First part in the name section, here it is `Debarghya` and the first section of `experience like google, facebook`I tried a lot but I can't find any solution. I just want to change the colour of the name and the subsections. Here's the [link](https://www.writelatex.com/templates/deedy-resume/sqdbztjjghvz#.U2H9Kq1dV18) to the resume.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us what you try so far. Question as it is probably will be closed soon as "unclear what you're asking" or "To Broad".

Comment: Well, you also should us tell what you want to change, the color of  `Das` or of `Debarghya` to which color? And which color should `Google` have? Do you see that it is printed in bold? Is only bold the culprit? Please explain your question better ...

Comment: I want to change `Debarghya` to **Blue**, and **Google, Facebook** to have `sky blue` colour. I was trying to do some modification and was thinking if that would look good or not. 
Thank you!

Comment: Can you also let me know how to use **MacFonts** instead of **OpenFonts** , just like mentioned [here](https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your question is not very clear, but your comments helped a little bit.

The template you use is not the best, for example takes command `\centering` no parameter als wrongly used in the template. See my correction in the part for `\namesection` ...

### Your first issue is "to change Debarghya to Blue":

The name is set by command `\namesection` so we have to redefine it like this (see the changed code lines marked with `<======`):

```
\renewcommand{\namesection}[3]{% <============= please see re in \renewcommand!
\centering% takes no parameter, works until command \namesection ends ...
{% <==================================================================== start group!
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont \textcolor{blue}{#1} % <=================
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2 % Lato-Lig <======
} \\[5pt] % <========================================================== end group, add newline with 5pt space
%\centering% not needed, takes no parameter, still working from first call!
{
\color{headings}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #3%
}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{headings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
\vspace{-15pt}
}
```

With `\textcolor{blue}{#1}` I added the color blue (standard blue, defined by package `xcolor`) only to the first argument of the name.  If you want that color too for the second parameter change the following `#2` to `\textcolor{blue}{#2}`.

### Your second issue is "to change [only!] Google, Facebook to have sky blue":

You did not tell what `sky blue` should be, so I defined it like that (change it for your needs):

```
\definecolor{skyblue}{HTML}{3333ff} % see documentation xcolor
```

Now we can redefine the command `\runsubsection` to typeset the complete line, containing your `Google` etc. you want to change to sky blue:

```
\renewcommand{\runsubsection}[1]{%
  \color{subheadings}%
  \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Reg}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}% Lato-Bol
  \selectfont%
  \bfseries%
  \textcolor{skyblue}{\uppercase {#1}} \normalfont% <===================
}
```

Please see the added `\textcolor{skyblue}{...}` in the marked line!

Now we can complete the code to the following mwe:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Deedy - One Page Two Column Resume
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.2 (16/9/2014)
%
% Original author:
% Debarghya Das (http://debarghyadas.com)
%
% Original repository:
% https://github.com/deedydas/Deedy-Resume
%
% IMPORTANT: THIS TEMPLATE NEEDS TO BE COMPILED WITH XeLaTeX
%
% This template uses several fonts not included with Windows/Linux by
% default. If you get compilation errors saying a font is missing, find the line
% on which the font is used and either change it to a font included with your
% operating system or comment the line out to use the default font.
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
% TODO:
% 1. Integrate biber/bibtex for article citation under publications.
% 2. Figure out a smoother way for the document to flow onto the next page.
% 3. Add styling information for a "Projects/Hacks" section.
% 4. Add location/address information
% 5. Merge OpenFont and MacFonts as a single sty with options.
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% CHANGELOG:
% v1.1:
% 1. Fixed several compilation bugs with \renewcommand
% 2. Got Open-source fonts (Windows/Linux support)
% 3. Added Last Updated
% 4. Move Title styling into .sty
% 5. Commented .sty file.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Known Issues:
% 1. Overflows onto second page if any column's contents are more than the
% vertical limit
% 2. Hacky space on the first bullet point on the second column.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}

%\definecolor{subheadings}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{skyblue}{HTML}{3333ff} % see documentation xcolor
\renewcommand{\runsubsection}[1]{%
  \color{subheadings}%
  \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Reg}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}% Lato-Bol
  \selectfont%
  \bfseries%
  \textcolor{skyblue}{\uppercase {#1}} \normalfont% <===================
}
\renewcommand{\namesection}[3]{%
\centering% takes no parameter, works until command \namesection ends ...
{% <==================================================================== start group!
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont \textcolor{blue}{#1} % <=================
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2 % Lato-Lig <======
} \\[5pt] % <========================================================== end group, add newline with 5pt space
%\centering% not needed, takes no parameter, still working from first call!
{
\color{headings}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #3%
}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{headings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
\vspace{-15pt}
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     LAST UPDATED DATE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lastupdated

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     TITLE NAME
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\namesection{Debarghya}{Das}{ \urlstyle{same}\href{http://debarghyadas.com}{debarghyadas.com}| \href{http://fb.co/dd}{fb.co/dd}\\
\href{mailto:deedy@fb.com}{deedy@fb.com} | 607.379.5733 | \href{mailto:dd367@cornell.edu}{dd367@cornell.edu}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     COLUMN ONE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EDUCATION
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Education} 

\subsection{Cornell University}
\descript{MEng in Computer Science}
\location{Dec 2014 | Ithaca, NY}
\sectionsep

\subsection{Cornell University}
\descript{BS in Computer Science}
\location{May 2014 | Ithaca, NY}
College of Engineering \\
Magna Cum Laude\\
\location{ Cum. GPA: 3.83 / 4.0 \\
Major GPA: 3.9 / 4.0}
\sectionsep

\subsection{La Martiniere for Boys}
\location{Grad. May 2011|  Kolkata, India}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     LINKS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Links} 
Facebook:// \href{https://facebook/dd}{\bf dd} \\
Github:// \href{https://github.com/deedydas}{\bf deedydas} \\
LinkedIn://  \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/debarghyadas}{\bf debarghyadas} \\
YouTube://  \href{https://www.youtube.com/user/DeedyDash007}{\bf DeedyDash007} \\
Twitter://  \href{https://twitter.com/debarghya_das}{\bf @debarghya\_das} \\
Quora://  \href{https://www.quora.com/Debarghya-Das}{\bf Debarghya-Das}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     COURSEWORK
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Coursework}
\subsection{Graduate}
Advanced Machine Learning \\
Open Source Software Engineering \\
Advanced Interactive Graphics \\
Compilers + Practicum \\
Cloud Computing \\
Evolutionary Computation \\
Defending Computer Networks \\
Machine Learning \\
\sectionsep

\subsection{Undergraduate}
Information Retrieval \\
Operating Systems \\
Artificial Intelligence + Practicum \\
Functional Programming \\
Computer Graphics + Practicum \\
{\footnotesize \textit{\textbf{(Research Asst. \& Teaching Asst 2x) }}} \\
Unix Tools and Scripting \\

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     SKILLS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Skills}
\subsection{Programming}
\location{Over 5000 lines:}
Java \textbullet{}   Shell \textbullet{} Python \textbullet{} Javascript \\
OCaml \textbullet{} Matlab \textbullet{} Rails \textbullet{} \LaTeX\ \\ 
\location{Over 1000 lines:}
C \textbullet{} C++ \textbullet{} CSS \textbullet{} PHP \textbullet{} Assembly \\
\location{Familiar:}
AS3 \textbullet{} iOS \textbullet{} Android \textbullet{} MySQL
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     COLUMN TWO
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EXPERIENCE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Experience}
\runsubsection{Facebook}
\descript{| Software Engineer }
\location{Jan 2015 - Present | New York, NY}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Coursera}
\descript{| KPCB Fellow + Software Engineering Intern }
\location{June 2014 – Sep 2014 | Mountain View, CA}
\vspace{\topsep} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space
\begin{tightemize}
\item 52 out of 2500 applicants chosen to be a KPCB Fellow 2014.
\item Led and shipped Yoda - the admin interface for the new Phoenix platform. 
\item Full-stack developer - Wrote and reviewed code for JS using Backbone, Jade, Stylus and Require and Scala using Play
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Google}
\descript{| Software Engineering Intern }
\location{May 2013 – Aug 2013 | Mountain View, CA}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Worked on the YouTube Captions team, in Javascript and Python to plan, to design and develop the full stack to add and edit Automatic Speech Recognition captions. In production.
\item Created a backbone.js-like framework for the Captions editor.
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Phabricator}
\descript{| Open Source Contributor \& Team Leader}
\location{Jan 2013 – May 2013 | Palo Alto, CA \& Ithaca, NY}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Phabricator is used daily by Facebook, Dropbox, Quora, Asana and more.
\item I created the Meme generator and more in PHP and Shell.
\item Led a team from MIT, Cornell, IC London and UHelsinki for the project.
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     RESEARCH
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Research}
\runsubsection{Cornell Robot Learning Lab}
\descript{| Researcher}
\location{Jan 2014 – Jan 2015 | Ithaca, NY}
Worked with \textbf{\href{http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ashesh/}{Ashesh Jain}} and \textbf{\href{http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asaxena/}{Prof Ashutosh Saxena}} to create \textbf{PlanIt}, a tool which  learns from large scale user preference feedback to plan robot trajectories in human environments.  
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Cornell Phonetics Lab}
\descript{| Head Undergraduate Researcher}
\location{Mar 2012 – May 2013 | Ithaca, NY}
Led the development of \textbf{QuickTongue}, the first ever breakthrough tongue-controlled game with \textbf{\href{http://conf.ling.cornell.edu/~tilsen/}{Prof Sam Tilsen}} to aid in Linguistics research. 
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     AWARDS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Awards} 
\begin{tabular}{rll}
2014         & top 52/2500  & KPCB Engineering Fellow\\
2014         & 1\textsuperscript{st}/50  & Microsoft Coding Competition, Cornell\\
2013         & National  & Jump Trading Challenge Finalist\\
2013     & 7\textsuperscript{th}/120 & CS 3410 Cache Race Bot Tournament  \\
2012     & 2\textsuperscript{nd}/150 & CS 3110 Biannual Intra-Class Bot Tournament \\
2011     & National & Indian National Mathematics Olympiad (INMO) Finalist \\
\end{tabular}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     PUBLICATIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Publications} 
\renewcommand\refname{\vskip -1.5em} % Couldn't get this working from the .cls file
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{publications}
\nocite{*}

\end{minipage} 
\end{document}
```

resulting in the following pdf:

[image: resulting cv]

As you can see in the image (red arrows) now only the name part `Debarghya` is blue and only `Google` (and not the complete line!) is in `skyblue` ...

A remark to the used fonts:  spread in the class you can find commands like

```
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont \textcolor{blue}{#1} % <=================
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont
```

(we already saw that in command `\namesection`) resulting in typing the first name `Debarghya` in font `Lato-Hai`, the second name `Das` in font `Lato-Lig`.

If you want to use other fonts you can change in `\fontspec` the names for the used fonts. I do not have a MaC, I can not help you with MaC fonts (but if you know the font name you can try to add it in the same way font `Lato` was used ...).

Comment: You're Awesome. Thank you so Much! :)

Comment: @NatashaSehgal see question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae for an overview about templates for cvs ...

Answer (score 2):

You should explain what you tried in order to resolve your request, and normally I state a template is designed (good or bad) for a purpose and the purpose here is monochromatic simplicity. However I do agree some spot colour might be desirable and am only going to point at the two locations you requested, you will need to determine what colour will grab attention or relegate your cv to the nearest round receptacle.

Note :- The mac fonts version is only for use on a mac that automatically should have those apple system fonts the location and names of colour changes for a mac user will be exactly the same but in the mac version

[image]

The colours are defined in each cls file so you need to check which one you are using (I am using deedy-resume-openfont.cls) and look for the following sections

```
% Color definitions
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\definecolor{date}{HTML}{666666} 
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{2b2b2b} 
\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{6A6A6A}
\definecolor{subheadings}{HTML}{ff3333} %<==change here for the subheading colour my edit ff=red 33=green 33=blue
```

For more blue you can change it to 3333ff sky blue should be 87ceeb ?

Find the name section

```
% Name command
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
\centering{
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt}
```

2) **Add your choice of name colour** after the \centering as I have done here

```
% Name command
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
\centering{\color{blue}
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just wanted to change the colour of Heading to blue. Just like you've done it. Yes, I do agree with you about  _monochromatic simplicity_ . But I thought, how would it look like if I just change the colour of heading. Also, how does the font in your template are different? I mean, is there any way to use the **Mac Font**. I am sorry, I'm new to LaTex. 
Thank you KJO, Best.

Comment: Thank you KJO, You've helped a lot!

Comment: I tried upvoting the answer, but since I'm new to this platform so I am getting , _Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score._