# Changing section font in a res document

Tags: formatting, titlesec, cv, resume, section-titles

I'm using `res.cls` to write a CV. I'd like to unbold the section title and use the italic font (as the picture below). 
[image: What I want]

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} % set width of text portion
\parskip = 0.5cm
\begin{document}
% Center the name
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf name}
% Draw a horizontal line
\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 1pt}\smallskip  
% address, email and phone
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{address}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{email}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{phone}
\begin{resume}
\section{EDUCATION}
\textbf{University of ...} \hfill 2015--2019\\ 
BSc in ..., May 2019
\section{EMPLOYMENT} 
...
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried to use the `titlesec` package. If I add

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\itshape}{}{}{}[]
```

to my code, it changes the position of my section title. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the used template is very old and should not used any longer, for example it still uses outdated commands like `\bf`.

Nevertheless, you can use in your preamble command

```
\renewcommand\sectionfont{\itshape}%\bf
```

to change the font for section from bold to italic.

BTW: the class is too old to be able to use package `titlesec` ...

Please see the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}

\renewcommand\sectionfont{\itshape}%\bf
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} % set width of text portion
\parskip = 0.5cm


\begin{document}
% Center the name
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf name}
% Draw a horizontal line
\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 1pt}\smallskip  
% address, email and phone
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{address}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{email}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{phone}

\begin{resume}
\section{EDUCATION}
\textbf{University of ...} \hfill 2015--2019\\ 
BSc in ..., May 2019
\section{EMPLOYMENT} 
...
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thank you, Mensch. Instead of res, what latex template would you recommend for writing a CV?

Comment: It depends on what you need. You can use class `article` and add wanted layout to it or you can for example use class `moderncv`, style `banking` looking simular to what you have with `res`. Have also a look to question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae

Comment: Okay, I'll try to modify my CV. Thanks a lot!