# personality using bar graphs

Tags: graphs, bar

I want to add  in my resume. How do I do that? I want similar to this.
Thx for ur help!
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the simple macro `\score` make the rule take full line width, and you should specify the labels and width of the left part as a two digits percentage.

Of course, because of the width of the red box, the score must be around between 08 and 92. Otherwise, it will out of the limits. If you need some extreme values, depend on how you want to deal with these cases, but a good start will be the red rule smaller.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\newcommand\score[3]{
{\par\medskip\huge\parindent0pt\sffamily#1\hfill#2\par\smallskip
\color{lightgray}\rule{\dimexpr.#3\linewidth-0.5em}{1em}%
\color{red!70!black}\rule{1em}{1em}%
\color{lightgray}\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-0.5em-.#3\linewidth}{1em}\par\medskip}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2][3-5]

\score{Passiv}{Aktiv}{17}

\score{Loyal}{Untreu}{67}

\lipsum[2][6-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted, thank you! :)